# How can i specify the app (created in the Google Play Console) i want to update using Fastlane?

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, continuous-integration, fastlane

I'm currently trying to setup continuous integration with help of "Fastlane".
The Project is ready to be build and uploaded to the Google Play Store. If I do this manually everything works fine.

We want to have three different Apps in Google Play (with three different identifiers [com.myapp, com.myapp.int, com.myapp.rc]). With only one of them being public. The reason behind that is to be able to install every environment on one device for testing purposes. This is of course not the most elegant way of achieving this. But I believe that it's [the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133896/can-i-install-different-google-play-tracks-on-the-same-device-at-the-same-time) and probably not without reasons.

So I'm able to build the app for different environments. The problem I'm currently facing is that if I want to upload them using Fastlane I'm only able to upload the one with the identifier `com.myapp` the other ones get the following error message:

```
[10:57:14]: fastlane finished with errors
[!] Google Api Error: forbidden: APK has the wrong package name. - APK has the wrong package name.
```

This sounds reasonable as I have never specified which app i want to update. If I manually upload the AAB I navigate to the right app inside the "Google Play Console" and upload it there but it seems that this option is not present in Fastlane (which would be pretty weird).
It is also weird that only one of them works as I wasn't even able to chose which one should work. How is Google/Fastlane choosing which App i want to update?

First i thought that the app would be specified inside the json key for google play. But I read in this [medium](https://shift.infinite.red/simple-react-native-android-releases-319dc5e29605#af5b) post that it would be the same one across different projects.

Here is my Fastfile:

```rb
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Runs all the tests"
  lane :test do
    gradle(task: "test")
  end

  desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Play Store"
  lane :beta do
    sh("cp", "../../.env.integration", "../../.env")
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'bundle',
      build_type: 'Release',
      print_command: false,
    )
    upload_to_play_store(
      track: 'internal'
    )
  end
end
```

And here is my Appfile:

```rb
json_key_file("~/.private_keys/google_api_key.json")
package_name("com.myapp")


for_platform :android do
  for_lane :beta do
    package_name("com.myapp.int")
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant script in your fastlane file.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I've added the contents of my Fastfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `package_name()` function you call in your Appfile will specify which App in Google Play fastlane should try to update.

However it does not determine the `applicationId` which gradle uses to build the App, so you have to make sure that these two values match.

Answer (score 3):

This is how we solved it:

```
    lane :build_lane do
        slack(message: "Starting build for myapp", default_payloads:[])
        build_android kFlavour:"myapp1" , kPackage_name:"com.abc.def"
    end
```

With this part:

```
    lane :build_android do | options |
        sh("flutter", "build", "appbundle", "--flavor", options[:kFlavour], "--no-sound-null-safety")
        slack(message: "Uploading " + options[:kFlavour] + " to playstore", default_payloads:[])
        upload_to_play_store(
            track: 'internal',
            track_promote_to:'alpha',
            version_code: flutter_version()["version_code"],
            version_name: flutter_version()["version_name"] + '+' + flutter_version()["version_code"],
            aab: "../build/app/outputs/bundle/"+options[:kFlavour]+"Release/app-" + options[:kFlavour] + "-release.aab",
            skip_upload_changelogs: true,
            skip_upload_screenshots: true,
            skip_upload_images: true,
            package_name: options[:kPackage_name],
        )
        slack(message: options[:kFlavour] + " successfully released on Android!", default_payloads:[])
    end
```

We added the package_name line in the upload_to_play_store()

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/#parameters), you can specify the path to an APK or AAB through the `apk` or `aab` parameter.

In your example you should be able to upload a specific android app bundle like this (replace `PATH_TO_AAB.aab` with actual relative or absolute path to the file):

```
upload_to_play_store(
  track: 'internal',
  aab: 'PATH_TO_AAB.aab'
)
```

### Alternative

Alternatively, you can create three different lanes for the three app versions you have.

In each lane you can then specify which flavor must be build in the gradle task.

For example if one of your flavors / versions has the name "pro", you can set the `build_type` in the `gradle` command to `ProRelease` instead of `Release`. This way, only the release version of the specific flavor is built.

```
desc "Submit a new Beta Build to Play Store"
  lane :beta do
    releaseFilePath = File.join(Dir.pwd, "..", "keystores","my-release-key.keystore")
    gradle(task: 'clean')
    gradle(
      task: 'bundle',
      build_type: 'ProRelease',
      print_command: false,
    )
    upload_to_play_store(
      track: 'internal'
    )
  end
```

Comment: I'm afraid i wasn't specific enough with my problem, my apologies. I've updated my question once more, providing more information.

The problem I'm facing is not the build itself. I'm able to build three different apps with three different identifiers (and environment variables). The problem only appears when Fastlane executes the `upload_to_play_store` function.